# Dynamic Excel Chart From Dataset

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a dataset with different units and dates for each unit that come back with readings of stuff in the oil and i'm trying to make a dynamic chart that I can do a drop down of said unit and a drop down for the date and element and for it to populate a chart.  I can't seem to get it right at all due to the third piece of data.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

an example is below
[image: Data Set]

Comment: To give meaningful help we need more background about what you're currently doing to solve this problem. However, this article might be of use https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Comment: if you select Unit, Date and one of the elements, you end up with just one number. What kind of chart do you want to build with that? Mock up the desired outcome manually and post that into your question.

Comment: Not sure if that can all be done in one step in Excel formulas.  You could however break it into parts potentially.  Build a list off to the side or another sheet that filters via formula for the information you are looking for.  Then turn around and make a named dynamic range where your filtered information is that you can use for graphing.  VBA you can program this all behind the scenes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let everyone know I had to put the data in a sqlite db and pull it from there